# LogUnsubEvent without JobId

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We're using a custom preference center. Within the Cloudpage Landingpage I want to add a button to optout. I do understand I need to use the LogUnsubEvent function (https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/using_ampscript_with_the_web_service_api/unsubscribe_and_log_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call/) to unsubscribe.

I'm just not sure how to generate the needed JobId to pass to the function, when the click does not come from an actual email but from a landingpage button, which doesn't have a jobId?

Comment: I generally put a conditional around JobId, ListId and BatchID to check if they have values.  If they don't, then I don't include it in the call.  If you don't specify one of these, then the subscriber is unsubscribed from the BU.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the [MicrositeURL](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/micrositeurl/#MicrositeURL) or [CloudPagesURL](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/cloudpagesurl/#cloudpagesURL) AMPscript function, they pass on the susbcriber context which includes things like `jobID`. You then use the [RequestParameter](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/requestparameter/#RequestParameter) function to capture this value

i.e.:

```
SET @jobID = RequestParameter("JobID")
```